# Python equivalent code to MATLABs vec2mat

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, reshape

I have a piece of code which I am converting from MATLAB to python. It is not yet written in a very pythonic way, but I will adapt it at a later stage.

The MATLAB script has the function `vec2mat` from the Communications systems toolbox. (See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html)  This works by changing a vector into a matrix by specifying the vector you wish to convert and the number of columns you wish to have. `mat = vec2mat(vec,matcol)`.

I would usually just use `numpy.reshape`. However, vec2mat adds zeros to the last row if there are not enough values in your vector to completely fill the last row.

The padding I require will vary depending on the csv file I input.

```
    atbmat = vec2mat(atbvec,nb);
```

In this example case `nb` is five and the length of `atbvec` is 4806. Therefore four zeros are added to the bottom row.

How would I go about adding the extra zeros in python to create a 2D array? I would have the 1D array  `atbvec` of length 4806 and `nb` equal to five (I want nb columns).

Thanks for any advice and I hope this makes sense.

**Edit**

```
     dim=len(atbvec)/int(nb)
     atbvec=np.array(atbvec)
     atbvec=np.copy(atbvec)
     atb_mat=atbvec.resize((dim,nb)
```

This is returning `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `resize()` method of an `numpy.ndarray` object:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
a.resize(2,3)
print a
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [0, 0, 0]])
```

---

EDIT:

Note that `a` is extended `in-place`, which means that the original array has now a reference to an extra, contiguous memory block.

In your case, based on the comments, you can previously create a copy:

```
atb_mat = atbvec.copy()
atb_mat.resize(dim, nb)
```

or, **preferably**, use `numpy.resize` to obtain a brand new array without references:

```
atb_mat = numpy.resize(atbvec, (dim, nb))
```

In this case, though, the array is filled with the previous values from `atbvec`, example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.resize(a, (3, 4))
#array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
#       [2, 3, 1, 2],
#       [3, 1, 2, 3]])
```

See that the memory block is copied until it fills the new contiguous-size.

Comment: Thanks alot for such a quick reply. That sounds like it should work. However, I am getting the output 'None' (**dim=len(atbvec)/int(nb)
     atbvec=np.array(atbvec)
     atb_mat=atbvec.resize((dim,nb))          
     print atb_mat
     return atb_mat**)

Comment: Except that `resize` simply adds zeros to the contiguous memory block. Consider `a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]).copy(); a.resize(3, 2)`.

Comment: @AshleighClayton this is because it resizes `in-place`, so your original array has now an extended memory block as mentioned by @HenryGomersall

Comment: do I create a copy? I used ` atbvec=np.copy(atbvec)`. Sorry, I'll add an edit in the bottom so it is a bit clearer

Comment: @AshleighClayton I've edited the answer since this matter is important to be clarified...

Comment: @AshleighClayton but you created a copy and threw away the previous array. You have to copy to the new array...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks a lot, solved my problem! Really clear answer

Comment: @AshleighClayton are you aware that it won't work if you need to resize on any axis except the most minor axis?

Comment: @HenryGomersall No I wasn't aware of this. I'm a bit unsure what you mean?

Comment: @HenryGomersall I don't see this limitation, maybe you can add one example as an edit in your answer...

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer. The problem is that the expansion is not shape aware and so just pads the data in memory, and not in the logical array.

Comment: Oh, me fail! It seems that `mat2vec` does do what you answer does (albeit, on row major data). I rather went from the question than the `Mathworks` page. I'll leave my answer up in case it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

**Overriding edit: It seems that I rather misunderstood the question, and solved a different one entirely. The solution below is if you need to expand or shrink an array to arbitrary size, padding with zeros as necessary.**

I'm not aware of a single function that does as you request (though I'm always learning!). The easiest way I can think of is probably to use `numpy.pad`. The following function does what you need as long as the new shape is larger than the old shape:

```
def vec2mat(a, new_shape):

    padding = (new_shape - numpy.vstack((new_shape, a.shape))).T.tolist()

    return numpy.pad(a, padding, mode='constant')
```

If you need to deal with both smaller and larger sizes than the original array, the following should do that:

```
def vec2mat(a, shape):

    padding = (shape - numpy.vstack((shape, a.shape))).T

    # Split into positive and negative padding
    neg_padding = padding.copy()
    neg_padding[neg_padding > 0] = 0
    padding[padding < 0] = 0

    # Turn the zero neg_paddings into None:
    slice_marks = [axis if axis[1] != 0 else (None,) for axis in neg_padding]

    # Make the slicer
    slicer = [slice(*each_mark) for each_mark in slice_marks]

    return numpy.pad(a[slicer], padding.tolist(), mode='constant')
```

Note that both of the above functions should operate on arbitrary dimension arrays.

Edit: The problem with `resize` as a solution is that it expands the array in memory only and then effectively reshapes that new memory block to your requested size. The effect of this is that if you're trying to expand along any axis other than the most minor axis, you'll run into problems. Consider expanding along the first axis:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3]).copy()
a.resize(2, 3)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0]])
```

which works as expected. However, now consider expanding along the last axis:

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]).copy()
a.resize(3, 2)
# array([[1, 2],
#        [3, 0],
#        [0, 0]])
```

I don't think that is what you want at all, though please correct me if I am wrong. My understand is that you require an array with the first column as `[[1],[2],[3]]` and the second column as all zeros.

Comment: If the OP want to expand with a second column, it is only required to use a memory layout wich is row-continuous, and this can be achieved if `a` is created with `a = np.array([1,2,3], order='F')`

Comment: Sorry, I just tested it here and it does not work... strange... it changes the memory layout, check `.flags`.

Comment: @SaulloCastro I don't think my solution does what is required anyway. It solves a different problem - specifically padding or shrinking an array along all dimensions.

Comment: @AshleighClayton it is indeed!